# javascript hide function not working codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have this jquery

```
$(function() {
  $('#LEAVE_ID').change(function() {
    if ($('#LEAVE_ID').val() == '1') {
      $('#1').show();
      $('#2').show();
      $('#3').show();
      $('#6').show();
    } else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() == '2') {
      $('#4').show();
      $('#5').show(); 
    } else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() == '7'){
      $('#specify').show(); 
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#LEAVE_ID').change(function() {
    if ($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '1') {
      $('#1').hide();
      $('#2').hide();
      $('#3').hide();
      $('#6').hide();
    } else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '2') {
      $('#4').hide();
      $('#5').hide(); 
    } else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '7'){
      $('#specify').hide(); 
    }
  });
});
```

all of this works fine except for `else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '7'){
      $('#specify').hide();`

and if it shows the div `$('#specify')` the whole javascript does not work at all.

`$('#1')-$('#6')` is radio buttons and  `$('#specify')` is a input type text

also

i also tried to put `.show();` and `.hide();` in one function but it doesnt work

html is

```
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" for="LEAVE_ID "><span>*</span>Leave Type:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control" name = "LEAVE_ID" id = "LEAVE_ID">
                      <option>--</option>
                        <?php foreach ($content as $leave) {?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $leave->LEAVE_ID; ?>"><?php echo $leave->LEAVE_TYPE; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" ></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="radio" style="display:none" id = "1">
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="1" name="REASON" value="To seek employment">
                          To seek employment
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio" style="display:none" id = "2">
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="2" name="REASON"  value="With in the Philippines">
                          With in the Philippines
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio" style="display:none" id = "3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="3" name="REASON"  value="Abroad">
                          Abroad
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio" style="display:none" id = "4">
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="4" name="REASON"  value="In hospital">
                          In hospital
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio" style="display:none" id = "5">
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="5" name="REASON"  value="Out Patient">
                          Out Patient
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="radio" style="display:none" id = "6">
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="6" name="REASON"  value="Others">
                          Others
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-body" style="display:none" id = 'specify'>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="SPECIFY" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2"><span>*</span>Specify:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                      <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="SPECIFY" name="SPECIFY" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                  <div class="form-group has-error col-sm-offset-7">
                    <label class="control-label" for="error"><?php echo form_error("SPECIFY"); ?></label>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Post your `html` too..

Comment: please try to create a jsfiddle

Comment: try it with affecting a css attribute like display none with .css()

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i updated it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('#LEAVE_ID').change(function() {
    if ($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '1') {
      $('#1').hide();
      $('#2').hide();
      $('#3').hide();
      $('#6').hide();
    } else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '2') {
      $('#4').hide();
      $('#5').hide(); 
    } else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '7'){
      $('#specify').hide(); 
    }
  });
});
```

problem with this part

lets debug this one if  $('#LEAVE_ID').val() value 5  it will execute on first **if** it will not execute remaining else ifs(i.e !=2 and !=7 ).change  like this.

```
  $(function() {
      $('#LEAVE_ID').change(function() {
        if ($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '1') {
          $('#1').hide();
          $('#2').hide();
          $('#3').hide();
          $('#6').hide();
        } 
        if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '2') {
          $('#4').hide();
          $('#5').hide(); 
        }
        if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() != '7'){
          $('#specify').hide(); 
        }
      });
    });
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

what i did is

```
$(function() {
  $('#LEAVE_ID').change(function() {
    if ($('#LEAVE_ID').val() == '1') {
      $('#1').show();
      $('#2').show();
      $('#3').show();
      $('#6').show();
      $('#4').hide();
      $('#5').hide(); 
      $('#specify').hide(); 
    } else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() == '2') {
      $('#1').hide();
      $('#2').hide();
      $('#3').hide();
      $('#6').hide();
      $('#4').show();
      $('#5').show(); 
      $('#specify').hide(); 
    }  else if($('#LEAVE_ID').val() == '7'){
      $('#1').hide();
      $('#2').hide();
      $('#3').hide();
      $('#6').hide();
      $('#4').hide();
      $('#5').hide(); 
      $('#specify').show(); 
    } else{
      $('#1').hide();
      $('#2').hide();
      $('#3').hide();
      $('#6').hide();
      $('#4').hide();
      $('#5').hide(); 
      $('#specify').hide();             
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about below function. First you can hide all radio button and than just show what ever you want. checkout below fiddle and code

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#LEAVE_ID').change(function() {
       $('div.radio').hide();
       $('#specify').hide();
      if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        $('#1,#2,#3,#6').show();
      } else if($(this).val() == '2') {
        $('#4,#5').show();
      } else if($(this).val() == '7'){
        $('#specify').show(); 
      } else {
        $('div.radio').show();
       $('#specify').show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

in the above function on change first it will hide all options and it will show only those options according to leave type selected and for else it will show all options.

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/04jftvmb/3/